# visual studio attach to process not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am trying to debug my production website using the code on my local system.
I am using VS2010, and tried all sorts of things still didn't work.
I tried using VS Development Server, and tried using IIS still didn't work.
When I attach the process debugger starts but break points were not hitting.
I tried attaching process to W3wp process, and tried attaching it to IE also.
Still its not hitting break points. Any idea whats causing this.
Thanks

Comment: If you haven't accessed the site, the process would not have loaded your assemblies into memory and the debugger will think you can't put a break point anywhere...

Comment: You might have old dll and pdb files cached. Check the gac

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to debug your production website remotely? I.e. you want to make a request against the production website and then break into the code on your local system? Or do you just mean that you are debugging the production *version* of your code, running on localhost?

Comment: Yes, I want to debug the production website remotely. How can I make a request against the production website.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "Remote Debugging".

Here is an MSDN link to get you started: [MSDN](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/233w9kd4.aspx&ei=XH4qUIn2M87qiQLRoYCgCg&usg=AFQjCNE3qZ68sUE_YQ1-7G7KpK2Fe5IeHg&sig2=JwmaaK0mUBeBADuflFMP2g)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the settings of Visual Studio
Tools->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->No…->next and set it

One more option, which worked for me is to open the VS in Safe Mode. It will 100% work:
Open Windows Explorer, and navigate to  \Common7\IDE;
Devenv /SafeMode: Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.